# Sass Modules Name Spacing with Filename in Dot Notation

Tags: sass

With Sass modules we can use the `@use` syntax for a filename when brought in and it will automatically namespace it to the name of the file.

So `@use '../foo'` will namespace everything behind `foo` so `foo.$color`.

But what is the namespace if the file has a dot in it?

So `@use '../bar.vars'` with the filename being `_bar.vars.scss`.

I can't seem to figure out if this breaks the name spacing or if it should be something automatically in this case.

I've tried `bar.vars.$color` but that doesn't work.  The only way I can get it to work is to remove the name spacing with `@use '../bar.vars' as *`.  This works but isn't ideal as we lose the power of name spacing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

An option would be changing the default namespace to another name.

`@use '../bar.vars' as <name>;`

example: `@use '../bar.vars' as b;`

also check if the relative link is working when you ctrl + click it.

Comment: Ah yeah that works as far as the rename namespace.  Relative link doesn't work for me using Scss IntelliSense for VSCode.  It doesn't seem to support `@use` yet